# how to make a grid item that uses remaining gridspace in reactjs material-ui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using material-ui grid in reactjs. In a column grid container, I want to use a grid item and I want to show another grid item. I want third item to use up the remaining grid space between the other 2 grid items. (i.e.) I want to show like

Grid Item 1

//remaining grid space

Grid Item 2

I have tried

```
<Grid container direction="column">
 <Grid item xs={12}>
  Grid Item 1
 </Grid>
 <Grid item xs={12} /> // this makes a space but not the entire space
 <Grid item xs={12}>
  Grid Item 2
 </Grid>
```

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're talking about the column grid in question but in code snippet, row is used. So I'm assuming a column grid.
Also Naima is making a valid point about giving `xs={12]}`. If you provide 12, then it'll take the entire rows/space.

```
<Grid container direction="column">
  <Grid item xs={3}>
    Grid Item 1
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={true}>
    // this makes a space but not the entire space
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={3}>
    Grid Item 2
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Setting `xs={true}`, will take the available space

Answer (score 2):

I am not getting why you are using `xs={12}` in all items ...
if you want the item will occupy remaining space.. it may solve your problem

```
<Grid container direction="row">
      <Grid item xs={3}>
        Grid Item 1
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs>
        Grid Item 2
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={3}>
        Grid Item 3
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: that's why i am asking here, i want to do like <div> Grid Item 1 </div> <div style="flex : 1"> <!--- remaining space --> </div> <div> grid item 2 </div> in html would allow the 2nd div to take all the remaining space. I want to achieve this in the div

Comment: have you checked the code... check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-moon-2eqvh)...
It will work the same way you are asking...

Comment: yes but i want this in a column container. In a single column, i want three items where first and third are as per my wish and the middle component takes up the remaining space. Just like in your code I want that in column direction that's all

Comment: May be [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-moon-2eqvh) one will be... what you want